# Error associated with HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

How can I solve this situation?

I'm using the IBMQX2 chip. When I run my simulation some circuits are executed and the following WARNING message is displayed:

```
account._job_result_object_storage:WARNING:2020-09-10 05:31:30,318: An error occurred while sending download completion acknowledgement: "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.quantum-computing.ibm.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=None)"
```

After a long time a few more circuits are run and the following error message is displayed:

```
IBMQBackendApiError: 'Error sending job: "HTTPSConnectionPool (host = \ 'api .quantum -computing.ibm.com \', port = 443): Reading timeout. (reading timeout = None) ".
```

At this point, the entire simulation is permanently stopped. When I used Windows 10 this type of message did not appear but, recently, I changed the operating system to Ubuntu 20.04. I don't know if it is necessary to do some kind of configuration on Linux.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please add more context? Whne this error occurs, for example?

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly a problem. When Qiskit finishes downloading a job result, it sends an acknowledgement to the server, so the server can do some cleanup. This warning (not error) message just says that the acknowledgement failed, which is usually due to temporary networking issues. This failed acknowledgement has no impact to you, as the result has already been downloaded.